# how to pass pandas dataframe as parameter to matplotlib library method plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, charts

how to pass pandas dataframe as parameter to matplotlib library method plot ?
For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df1.as_matrix(['Score']),df1.as_matrix(['Score']))
```

Comment: Look at `df.values`.

Comment: `plt.plot(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for convert `Series` to `numpy array`:

```
plt.plot(df1['Score'].values, df1['Col'].values)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot(x='Score',y='Col')
```

Comment: I line is not displayed in graph after executing the below code. Please help me.                                                                                             import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xl = pd.read_csv(C:\Test.csv)
df = pd.DataFrame(xl, columns=('Time','Mark','Score'))
plt.plot(df['Mark'].values,df['Score'].values)

Comment: I added "plt.show()" but it is not showing line in chart

Comment: are values numeric? what return `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: and better is use instead `xl = pd.read_csv(C:\Test.csv) df = pd.DataFrame(xl, columns=('Time','Mark','Score'))` this `df = pd.read_csv(C:\Test.csv) df.columns=['Time','Mark','Score']`

Comment: I got error message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01.10.2015 00:00:00.000'". if I use Time field in plot "plt.plot(df['Time'].values,df['Mark'].values)"

Comment: I think you need convert `Time`  column to datetime by `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`. If not working in matplotlib, try second solution with `df.plot(x='time',y='Mark')`

Comment: Great Jezrael that works,Thank You Very Much for understanding
my problem quickly and providing quick response.